# Mysql Command required for getting values from my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5

I am new to MySQL DBA, i have a doubt, Is there any command for finding my.cnf configuration file variables and its respective value which is mention in my.cnf file in mysql prompt itself. like we will see the global variable which are there in mysql in below format
mysql> show variable like'xxxx';

Similar kind of command is there for seeing all parameter present in my.cnf.

Comment: Are you using MySQL for Linux or Windows ???

Answer (score 1):

You could use this reference: [MySQL Documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html)

For example:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES;
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                               |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment        | 1                                   |
| auto_increment_offset           | 1                                   |
| automatic_sp_privileges         | ON                                  |
| back_log                        | 50                                  |
…
```

> To obtain the row for a specific variable, use a LIKE clause as shown:
>
> `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%size%';`
>   `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%size%';`

Comment: Am using Linux OS.By using show command am not getting below parameter vaule through mysql prompt. Replicate_Wild_Do_Table

Answer (score -1):

By using below command we can read the my.cnf or any file content through prompt.

```
mysql>/! cat /etc/my.cnf
```